# Factorial derivatives and generating functions of natural powers

Tags: calculus, derivatives, generating-functions, factorial

I'm looking for a series of functions like that:$$f_k^{(n)}(x)\mid_{x=0}=n^kn!$$
Here are the first and second functions:
$$f_0(x)=\frac 1{1-x}$$$$f_1(x)=\frac x{(1-x)^2}$$
That's because
$\frac 1{1-x}^{(n)}\mid_{x=0}=n!\text{ and }\frac x{(1-x)^2}^{(n)}\mid_{x=0}=nn!$

You maybe have notice that those functions are generating function, the first for $\mathbb N$ and the second for $\mathbb N^2$, it's easy to see that $f_k$ is the generating function for $\mathbb N^{k+1}$.

So what I'm actually asking is what is the generating function of:$$\{0^k,1^k,2^k,3^k,\dots\}$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number#Identities

Comment: thanks, this is very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Since the powers can be expressed as a linear combinations of the Falling Factorials through the Stirling N. of 2nd kind as
$$
x^{\,n}  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\left\{ \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right\}\,x^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } } 
$$
then
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,\,k} {k^{\,m} \;z^{\,k} } \quad \left| {\;{\rm 0} \le {\rm integer }m} \right.\quad  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,\,k} {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,\,j\,\left( { \le \,m} \right)} {\left\{ \matrix{
  m \cr 
  j \cr}  \right\}k^{\,\underline {\,j\,} } \;z^{\,k} } }  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,\,j} {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,\,k} {\left\{ \matrix{
  m \cr 
  j \cr}  \right\}j!\left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  j \cr}  \right)\;z^{\,k} } }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j\,\left( { \le \,m} \right)} {\left\{ \matrix{
  m \cr 
  j \cr}  \right\}} {{j!z^{\,j} } \over {\left( {1 - z} \right)^{\,j + 1} }} =   \cr 
  &  = \left[ {0 = m} \right] + {z \over {\left( {1 - z} \right)^{m + 1} }}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j\,\left( { \le \,m} \right)} {\left\langle \matrix{
  m \cr 
  j \cr}  \right\rangle z^{\,j} }  \cr} 
$$
where the angle brackets denotes the [Eulerian N. of 1st kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number)